# Updating DataGridView.BackColor on a background thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I have an application with a DataGridView on which multiple people could be working at the same time. I want to have each user's current row location displayed via a different colour row in the DataGridView.

Previously I was doing all of this updating via the `RowEnter` event however the performance is not satisfactory, for obvious reasons.

I'm trying to have a background thread which loops every 10 seconds to populate a DataTable with keys of the other users' locations which then references a key column in the DGV, and if they match, change the DGV row background color else set it to the default.

My current code, below, loops every 10s but it doesn't actually update the DGV.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ActiveThread = True
    dgvThread = New Thread(AddressOf UpdateDGVFromThread) With {
        .IsBackground = True}
    dgvThread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateDGVFromThread()
    Do While ActiveThread = True

        'Sets table with key values
        dtUsers = CLS_USERS.GetUsers(User)

        'Loop through them
        For Each row As DataRow In dtUsers.Rows
            intSeq = row("SEQUENCE")

            'Loop through each DGV row and compare the values
            For Each dgv_row As DataGridViewRow In dgvCandList.Rows
                dgvCandList.BeginInvoke(
                    Sub()
                        If dgv_row.Cells("CURRENT_CAND_SQ").Value = intSeq Then
                            dgv_row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan
                        Else
                            dgv_row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan
                        End If
                    End Sub)
            Next
        Next
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Loop
End Sub
```

I tried using **`dgv.Invoke()`** rather than **`.BeginInvoke()`** but this seemed to lock up the UI thread constantly and only the DGV was unlocked.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're not using a Timer for this. Anyway, try calling the update Sub with a MethodInvoker: `dgvCandList.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() (...) End Sub))`. Don't use `Invoke()`. Test the whole thing using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (the `Tick` event is raised in the UI thread) instead of a thread.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. MethodInvoker has done the trick. I never knew that existed. If you want to put that as an answer I'll mark it as such. Is there a particular benefit to using Timer rather than just sleeping the thread? I don't need the timer on the UI at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) method is used to asynchronously invoke a method delegate on the thread that created the Control's handle. The UI thread, here. It's signature is:

```
Public Function BeginInvoke (method As Delegate) As IAsyncResult
```

The **`method`** Delegate is then declared in the same thread where the Control invoked has been created.
The delegate should then be declared like this:

In the UI thread:

```
Delegate Sub MyUpdateDelegate()

Public Sub MyUpdateMethod()
   [SomeControl].Text = "Updated Text"
End Sub
```

In another thread:

```
Private Sub InvokeFromAnotherThread()
   'Prefer the Parent Form as marshaller
   Me.BeginInvoke(New MyUpdateDelegate(AddressOf MyUpdateMethod))
   '(...)
   'You can also use a Control, but the Parent Form is better
   [SomeControl].BeginInvoke(New MyUpdateDelegate(AddressOf MyUpdateMethod))
End Sub
```

Using an anonymous method in-place won't cut it.

There's a shortcut, provided by the [MethodInvoker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker) delegate:

> MethodInvoker provides a simple delegate that is used to invoke a
> method with a void parameter list. This delegate can be used when
> making calls to a control's Invoke method, or when you need a simple
> delegate but do not want to define one yourself.

Using a `MethodInvoker` delegate, there's no need to declare a delegate in the UI thread. An anonymous method can be used here, it will be invoked in the UI thread:

```
Private Sub InvokeFromAnotherThread()
   '(...)
   BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() [SomeControl].Text = "Updated Text"))
   '(...)
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Private Sub InvokeFromAnotherThread()
   '(...)
    BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(
        Sub()
            [SomeControl].Text = "Updated Text"
            [SomeOtherControl].BackColor = Color.Red
        End Sub))
   '(...)
End Sub
```

---

Why I suggested a Timer:
The thread you're using has one task only: update a Control in the UI thread and then sleep.
To perform this task, it needs to invoke a method in the UI thread. If the reason why the thread has been created is to avoid blocking the UI thread, a Timer will do the same thing. A `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, specifically, will raise its `Tick` event in the UI thread, without cross-thread calls.
The practical effect is more or less the same.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I will certainly look into using a Timer as this does seem to do what I need and would be a lot simpler.

Comment: It can surely simplify the process. You have to update the UI in any case, so some stuttering is always possible (in any case) if you have many rows to update. Another advantage (I haven't written about this, but I will) is that an exception raised while `BeginInvoke`ing, is by definition *untrappable*: it will bubble up to the Application level.